# SHChangeNotifyRegister->SHCreateItemFromIDList->IShellItem2 has no FILETIME information on SHCNE_CREATE?

Tags: winapi, windows-shell

Given `SHChangeNotifyRegister()` of a folder where a new item is being watched and detected via `SHCNE_CREATE` and converting the `PIDL` to `IShellItem2` using `SHCreateItemFromIDList()` the attempt to `IShellItem2::GetFileTime(PKEY_DateCreated, &createtime);` fails with `ERROR_NOT_FOUND` (Element not found).   Same if I try `PKEY_DateModified`.   How can that be?  Is there a way to include the date (break on debug shows the file already exists, can be seen in windows explorer and has a date/time).  Is there something else to do or it doesn't pass that information?  The `IShellItem2::GetDisplayName()` works fine.  This is Win10 x64?

TIA!!

Comment: While handling `SHCNE_CREATE`, does [`GetFileTime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfiletime) or [`FindFirstFile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilew) work to get the times you want?

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you retrieve the ShellItem's [`IPropertyStore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/propsys/nn-propsys-ipropertystore) and call its [`GetValue()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/propsys/nf-propsys-ipropertystore-getvalue) method for the times? If you enumerate the store's values, what keys are actually present?

Comment: Rather than using `IShellItem2` at all, are you able to get the times from [`SHGetDataFromIDList(SHGDFIL_FINDDATA)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetdatafromidlistw)?

Comment: I had put in the FindFileFirst() method as a workaround, I'll check those others out.

Comment: This should work fine, unless the shell item underneath doesn't support PKEY_DateCreated, PKEY_DateModified (not all items in the namespace do). Standard physical file system items should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a PIDL only contains the name and no other information you are looking at a simple item. These are generated by `SHSimpleIDListFromPath` when the change notifier only knows the path or if the notifier used a empty find info in the bind context when creating the PIDL.

Your only option is to hit the disk and fill in a new PIDL. In generic shell namespace speak this means asking `IShellFolder` to parse the display-name. `IShellItem2::Update` might do this for you, the documentation does not say if it is valid for simple items.

Comment: Strictly speaking, a IShellFolder implementation defines the contents of its child PIDLs and it could in theory not contain any names at all but it would still have to support extracting a name when asked. The MS implementation for normal filesystem folders contains the name as given by the FindFirst function family.